# Asp.net Modal Edit Partial View Not Keeping Dropdownlist Value

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

When the modal pops open the values that were originally selected for the drop down list have been changed to the first item on the list.  How do I keep the values that were originally selected?

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult AddEditExam(int exam_id)
    {
        exam exam = new exam();

        ViewBag.credential_id = new SelectList(db.credentials, "credential_id", "credential_code", exam.credential_id);
        ViewBag.credential_status_id = new SelectList(db.credential_status, "credentials_status_id", "credentials_status_description", exam.credential_status_id);

        if (exam_id > 0)
        {
            exam ex = db.exams.SingleOrDefault(x => x.exam_id == exam_id);
            exam.exam_id = ex.exam_id;
            exam.credential_id = ex.credential_id;
            exam.credential_status = ex.credential_status;
            exam.exam_desc = ex.exam_desc;
            exam.exam_last_update = ex.exam_last_update;
            exam.exam_passing_score = ex.exam_passing_score;
            exam.exam_time = ex.exam_time;          
        }
        return PartialView("AddEdit", exam);
    }
```

Partial View: Slimmed down to drop down list

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.credential_id, "credential_id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        @Html.DropDownList("credential_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.credential_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })




    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.credential_status_id, "credential_status_id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        @Html.DropDownList("credential_status_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.credential_status_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnSubmit1").click(function () {
        $("#loaderDiv").show();
        var myModelBody1 = $("#myForm").serialize();

        if (!$("#myForm").valid()) {
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("index", "exams")",
            data: myModelBody1,
            success: function () {
                $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                $('#myModalAddEdit').modal('hide');
                window.location.href = "@Url.Action("index", "exams")";

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Original View: Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalAddEdit">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
            <h3 class="modal-title"><strong style="color:#ff9c21">EDIT </strong> Exam</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="myModelBody1">


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" id="btnSubmit1" class="btn btn-warning" value="Update">Update</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Original View: Modal Script

```
 var AddEditExam = function (exam_id) {

    var exam_id = exam_id;

    var url = '@Url.Action("AddEditExam", "exams")?exam_id=' + exam_id;
    //var url = "http://localhost/NAHP/exams/AddEditExam?exam_id="+exam_id;
    $("#myModelBody1").load(url,
        function() {
            $("#myModalAddEdit").modal('show');
        });

}
```

Comment: Can you try using DropDownListFor instead in popup partial view?

Comment: All all the possible ways to generate a `<select>` you have chosen the worst - the one that is not strongly binding to your model, will never select the correct option, the one that will not give your correct client side validation etc. Your editing data so use a view model (that will contain a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CredentialList` and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.credential_id, Model.CredentialList, new { .... })`

Comment: But why in the world are you using ajax and then redirecting using `location.href` - the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. Just make a normal submit. Writing all that extra code in order to degrade performance is pointless.